# Dynamically change the DisplayMemberPath of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

Say I want to fill a ComboBox with a list of simple Employee objects...

```
public class Employee
{
    private int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }

}
```

and then bind that list through XAML like this...

```
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeList}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEmployee}"
                      DisplayMemberPath="Project"/>
```

Now I can use this ComboBox to look up and select Employee records by Project.  But if an Employee doesn't currently have a Project associated to them I would also like the ability to look up records (using the same ComboBox and bindings) by Name or Department if I so choose. Any ideas on how would I implement something that will make changes to the DisplayMemberPath value like I described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DisplayMemberPath is just [a string property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(v=vs.110).aspx). Bind to it in your viewmodel.

```
<ComboBox ...
   DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DispMemberPath}"
/>
```

Viewmodel...

```
private string _DispMemberPath;
public string DispMemberPath
{ 
  get {return _DispMemberPath; }
  set { _DispMemberPath= value; RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

private void SetDepartmentAsPath()
{
    this.DispMemberPath = "Department";
}
```